# cudaMemcpy2D to mat

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am going to use the grabcutNPP from cuda sample in order to speed up the image processing. The original sample code is implemented for FIBITMAP, but my input/output type will be Mat.

I had figured out most of the code but stuck in the `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` step...As a CUDA beginner, I have no reason why it always stops at this step

Here is part of my code :

```
void grabcutGPU(Mat& _src, Mat& _dst, Rect _srcRect){

GrabCut *grabcut;
const size_t width = _src.rows;
const size_t height = _src.cols;
size_t image_pitch; 
size_t result_pitch;
size_t trimap_pitch;
uchar4 *gpu_src, *gpu_dst;
unsigned char *d_trimap;
NppiRect rect;


// rect to nppirect
rect.x = _srcRect.x;
rect.y = _srcRect.y;
rect.width = _srcRect.width;
rect.height = _srcRect.height;


//melloc for src_image
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&gpu_src, &image_pitch, width * sizeof(uchar4), height));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(gpu_src, image_pitch, _src.ptr<uchar4>(), width * sizeof(uchar4), width * sizeof(uchar4), height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
// melloc foe rect
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&d_trimap, &trimap_pitch, width, height));


// Setup GrabCut
grabcut = new GrabCut(gpu_src, (int)image_pitch, d_trimap, (int)trimap_pitch, width, height);
//rect to memory
checkCudaErrors(TrimapFromRect(d_trimap, (int)trimap_pitch, rect, width, height));

//grabcut segmentation
grabcut->computeSegmentationFromTrimap();

//melloc for dst_image
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&gpu_dst, &result_pitch, width * 4, height));
//GPU process
checkCudaErrors(ApplyMatte(2, gpu_dst, (int)result_pitch, gpu_src, (int)image_pitch, grabcut->getAlpha(), grabcut->getAlphaPitch(), width, height));
size_t output_pitch = result_pitch;

//send result to dst
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(_dst.ptr(), (int)output_pitch, gpu_dst, result_pitch, width * 4, height, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

delete grabcut;
checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize(), "Kernel Launch Failed");
checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(gpu_src), "CUDA Free Failed");
checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(gpu_dst));
checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_trimap), "CUDA Free Failed");}
```

Comment: is your image pixel type uchar4? Standard is Vec3b which should be equal to uchar3.

Comment: width is cols and height is rows!

Comment: Because there is an alpha channel for grabcut, this is the reason I use uchar4. Does it mean that I couldn't pass the result to Mat? Or I should do some extra processing?

Comment: test if image_pitch.channels() == 4. If it is 3 instead, use `cv::cvtColor(image_pitch, image_pitch, CV_BGR2BGRA)` if your image is in BGR ordering (which is default in openCV when loading or capuring).

Comment: It works after converting BGR to BGRA! Thanks a lot!

Comment: awesome, write an answer yourself if you like to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is solved.

First of all, the row and col are carelessly mistaken.

Then, the input mat were 3 channels but this function needs 4 channels mat for passing result. It could be solved by converting colour type.

Thanks to Micka, or I might never notice the channel problem.